# Sub-queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, jupyter

I have two working queries and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make the 2nd a subquery in the first query.

Query 1:

```
SELECT w.ws_property_id AS WID, w.property_type AS WProp
FROM watershed_property_info w
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT w.property_type
                 FROM st_property_info s            
                 WHERE w.property_type=s.property_type)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT d.st_property, COUNT(d.rental_date)
FROM st_rental_dates d
WHERE YEAR(rental_date) = '2015'
GROUP BY st_property
```

The result should return the d.rental_date in st_rental_dates for ONLY the 244 matching st_property rows in st_rental_dates but every time I try to combine these 2 queries I get 14,888 rows.  I'm having a hard time understanding where to put what when doing sub-queries. Any advice?

Comment: Can you list the primary/foreign keys for each table? It's not clear but it sounds more like you need a join than a subquery.

Comment: for the database we got, these are assumed PK and FK.  w.ws_property_id (PK), w.location (FK), w.property_type(FK); s.st_property_id (PK), s.location(FK), s.property_type(FK); d.rental_date(PK), d.st_property(PK)